# Loading NIB file using NSWindowController work but window not visible

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindowcontroller

Loading NIB file using NSWindowController work but when window did loaded it showing and immediately hide. What happen? I don't know. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)loadMyWindow:(id)sender
{
    NSWindowController * windowController;

    if (windowController == nil) {
        windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"myWindow"];
       [windowController window];
    }
}
```

Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In project with ARC we must announce a variable `windowController` outside the method `loadMyWindow`

```
NSWindowController *windowController; //for example here

- (IBAction)loadMyWindow:(id)sender
{
    if (windowController == nil) {
        windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"myWindow"];
       [windowController window];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the line `[windowController showWindow:self]`

Comment: Try creating an outlet for your window and initing your windowController using `windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindow:window]` and then add `[windowController showWindow:self]`